# How can I make fontawesome work in a Vue project in production builds?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, font-awesome

I am building a small project with Vue, typescript, vuetify and icons from fontawesome5. But I am coming across a weird challenge that I cant overcome. In dev mode, all the icons are showing fine from font awesome, but when I build for production, the icons show as square boxes. So far, all my components, custom vuetify theme, backend api, everything works as expected in my build, but not the icons. I also noticed that during prod builds, the fontawesome fonts are not are being included which explains the problem. I did try setting a direct link to fontawesome cdn in index.html but that does work either.

My setup is simple. Project intialized with

- `vue create .`
- `vue add vuetify`

So far, this is what I have tried/made sure of are:

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
```

So css is being imported. I have tried moving around this imoort statement, but that doesnt solve it.

Vuetify init

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#3577F6',
        secondary: '#424242',
        accent: '#82B1FF',
        error: '#FF5252',
        info: '#5543BD',
        success: '#00695c',
        warning: '#F6BC41'
      },
      dark: {
        primary: '#3577F6',
        secondary: '#424242',
        accent: '#82B1FF',
        error: '#FF5252',
        info: '#5543BD',
        success: '#00695c',
        warning: '#F6BC41'
      }
    },
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
  },
});
```

I tried moving the css import here, but thats a no go.

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run docs",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "docs": "./node_modules/.bin/redoc-cli bundle ./docs/swagger.yml --output ./dist/docs.html --options.hideDownloadButton"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "store2": "^2.11.2",
    "typeface-open-sans": "0.0.75",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-matomo": "^3.13.5-0",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.155",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.4.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.4.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.4",
    "redoc-cli": "^0.9.8",
    "sass": "^1.26.8",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

Some mention that css-loader is required along with webpack, so I did install css loader but that didnt solve it.

Because I am using the standard vue cli (version @vue/cli 4.4.1), i didnt see a webpack config file.

Dev mode:
[image]

Prod serving built files:
[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue is likely...

that the `$fa-font-path` is not defined, and the fonts can't be found.

#### Solution

Create (and reference in your project) an scss file (like `styles.scss`) with the following

```css
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css';
```

this should have it included by webpack

or if you want a specific font pack...

```css
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
```

or you can use the `<style>` block

```html
<style lang="scss">
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css';
</style>
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a reference to the solution? I dont have a webpack conf file in the project, so as expected, i am getting the `This dependency was not found:
* -!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js` error

Comment: you can also use the `<style lang="scss">` block

Comment: The style lang block didnt work, but what ended up working was importing specific font packs

Comment: interesting, I expected that including `$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';` should have resolved it

Comment: I thought so also, but it was still throwing the `This dependency was not found: * -!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js` error on build. but doing `@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';...` fixed the icons and build

Comment: I wonder if it could be due to the the variable not liking aliases, but looks like you got it to work, so 